# Error RSpec ActionController::UrlGenerationError with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm getting an error when trying to test a Rails Controller with RSpec. It's a double nested route and I'm trying to figure out the right syntax but hadn't had many luck yet.

The error that I'm getting is
    Failure/Error: get :index, {category_id: category.to_param, id: system.to_param}

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
 No route matches {:action=>"index", :category_id=>"220", :controller=>"reviews", :id=>"166"}
 # ./spec/controllers/reviews_controller_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I've made the same test for the system controller which works fine. The webpage works fine as well. No errors with that (just this error with testing).

Here is what the RSpec test look like:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe ReviewsController, type: :controller do

  let (:category) { create(:category) }
  let (:system) { create(:system) }
  let (:reviews) { create_list(:review, 3, category: category, system: system) }

 describe "GET index" do
   it "assigs all reviews to an instance var called @reviews" do
    get :index, {category_id: category.to_param, id: system.to_param}
    expect(assigns(:reviews)).to eq reviews
   end

  it "assigns all the reviews to an var called @system" do
   get :index, system_id: system.to_param
   expect(assigns(:system)).to eq system
  end
 end

 describe "system scope" do
  before { create(:review) }

  it "only assigns reviews index in the current system" do
   get :index, {category_id: category.to_param, id: system.to_param}
   expect(assigns(:reviews)).to eq reviews
  end
 end
end
```

This is the Controller that it's testing:

```
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController

  def index
   @system = System.find(params[:system_id])
   @reviews = @system.reviews

  respond_to do |format|
   format.html
   format.json { render json: { system: @system, reviews: @reviews } }
  end

 end

 def show
  @system = System.find(params[:system_id])
  @review = @system.reviews
 end

end
```

And these are the routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root "categories#index"

  resources :categories do
    resources :systems do
      resources :reviews
    end
  end
end
```

Here are the models:

Category Model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :name

  has_many :systems

end
```

System Model

```
class System < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :category
  has_many :reviews

  validates_presence_of :name, :category

end
```

Review Model

```
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :system

  validates_presence_of :content, :system

end
```

Comment: Where are your `routes`?

Comment: Made a mistake. I've edited so you can see the routes.

Answer (score 0):

> ActionController::UrlGenerationError:  No route matches
>   {:action=>"index", :category_id=>"220", :controller=>"reviews",
>   :id=>"166"}

According to your routes, that particular `index` route expects `category_id` and `system_id` as keys. You need to change `:id` to `:system_id`. The below should work.

```
it "only assigns reviews index in the current system" do
  get :index, {category_id: category.to_param, system_id: system.to_param}
  expect(assigns(:reviews)).to eq reviews
end
```

***Update***

> NoMethodError: undefined method `category=' for
>   Review:0x005578a9e87188

There is no association between a `review` and a `category`. Edit your models to set the association accordingly.

```
#category.rb
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  has_many :systems
  has_many :reviews
end

#review.rb
class Review < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :system
  belongs_to :category
  validates_presence_of :content, :system
end
```

Comment: When I'm doing that I get an error:  NoMethodError:
       undefined method `category=' for #<Review:0x005578a9e87188>

Comment: @Samuel What are your models like? Update the question with the model code.

Comment: thanks for thinking along but I'm not going to change the models because the test is failing. The site works fine. There has to another way to make the test.